# jQuery/js conditional statement not going through

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

First statement works, but not the last. Can't resolve.

First press should show first hidden thing, then second press should show third hidden thing then the button should delete itself. Let's play spot the syntax error (unless I really screwed up.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#v2i").hide();
    $("#v3i").hide();
    $("#vAdd").click(function(){
        if ($("#v2i").not(":visible")) {
            $("#v2i").show();
        } else if ( ($("#v2i").is(":visible")) && ($("#v3i").not(":visible")) ) {
            $("#v3i").show();
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: seems very convoluted - surely a toggle could be used somewhere in here?

Comment: @gavgrif I don't think toggle could be used for this 3-way logic.

Comment: @Barmar - I call cobblers on that - but anyway I did a diffferent approach and have created a smaller and cleaner approach. Given that in reality all that is happening is a sequential reveal of the elements and a hiding of the button when both elements are shown - i have posted a solution. I look forward to your thoughts :)

Comment: @TJW - I know the solution has already been accepted - but i believe in trying new ways to achieve the stated outcome. Have a look at my solution and see if you like it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.not()` isn't a test, it's used for selecting elements. You don't need to use `not`, because jQuery has a `:hidden` selector, which is the opposite of `:visible`. You need to write:

```
    if ($("#v2i").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#v2i").show();
    } else if ( ($("#v2i").is(":visible")) && ($("#v3i").is(":hidden")) ) {
        $("#v3i").show();
        $(this).hide();
    }
```

Also, there's no need to check `#v2i` in the second `if`, since you already tested it in the first `if`. You'll only get to the `else if` if `#v2i` is visible. So it should just be:

```
    if ($("#v2i").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#v2i").show();
    } else if ($("#v3i").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#v3i").show();
        $(this).hide();
    }
```

Comment: I've updated the answer, you also had a bad `.not()` in the first `if`.

Comment: That part **seemed** to work for me, but I replaced it with that snippet and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A different approach - rather than using if statements - using a class name and then using querySelectorAll to remove the hidden class and show the element.

Note that I have created a dummy version of the elements and have included the id as the text in all cases. In reality - all that is happening is a sequential reveal of the hidden elements (first v2i and then v3i) so it really doesn't need  an if statement - rather a hidden class applied to each element and then on the click of the button a sequential removal of the hidden class (revealing the element) and then when the last element is revealed the vAdd button itself is hidden.

Its always better to remove unecessay if logic and using a different approach like this extends boundaries and allows new ideas. and yes i know that there is the ternary operator in there which is a shorthand if statement - but i stilll like this approach. :)

I know the solution has already been accepted - but i believe in trying new ways to achieve the stated outcome.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#vAdd").click(function(){
     var el = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
     el[0].classList.remove('hidden');
     el.length == 1 ? $(this).hide() : $(this).show();
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="v2i" class="hidden">v2i</div>
<div id="v3i" class="hidden">v3i</div>
<hr/>
<button id="vAdd">vAdd - click me</button>
```